# Pass parameter to ng-template is underfined with nbpopover

Tags: angular, popover, ngfor, nebular, ng-template

I am using `nbPopover` and I just want to pass context to `nbPopover`. usually its working but now I would like to use this inside `*ngIf` and after that all pass data are undefined. here is sample=>

```
  <div *ngFor="let value of valuelist;let i = index">               
       <div [nbPopover]="templateRef" [nbPopoverContext]="{passdata:value}" nbTooltipStatus="basic" nbPopoverTrigger="click">                       
            <label>Box {{i+5}}</label>                       
       </div>
 </div>


 <ng-template #templateRef let-work="passdata">
    <div>     
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>: {{work}}</label><br />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
  </ng-template>
```

I already used this `nbPopoverContext` without `ngfor` and it's working but after I use this inside `ngfor`, it's not working anymore. How can I solve this issue? thanks, guys.

Comment: wouldn't passing the index too in the context work?

Comment: Theres no need for ngFor here.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, May I know why it's not needed?

Comment: @eko, not working also

Comment: can You share `valueList` object  ?

Comment: @Loran nbPopoverContext is used to pass context to custom component and not for ng-template. If you declare custome component and used @Input() prop then you will get context from popover context

Comment: If you want example then I can share here.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, Thank you. If u can share the example, it will be great. but I also check here => [https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/playground/with-layout/popover/popover-test.component.ts] .Also, use the ng-template but not with ngfor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231572/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-loran).

Comment: Come to discussion panel by clicking over above link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231572/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-loran

Answer (score 0):

I bumped on this example and it worked:

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/playground/with-layout/popover/popover-template-ref.component.html

So for your snippet, it should be something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of valuelist;let i = index">               
       <div [nbPopover]="templateRef" [nbPopoverContext]="{work:value}" nbTooltipStatus="basic" nbPopoverTrigger="click">                       
            <label>Box {{i+5}}</label>                       
       </div>
 </div>    

 <ng-template #templateRef let-passdata>
    <div>     
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <label>: {{passdata.work}}</label><br />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
  </ng-template>
```